# Defining consistent (and legal) import style in Pycharm

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, python-import

My Pycharm is autogenerating imports of this form: `from submodule.subsub import myfunction`. The `root` module , under which `submodule` sits, is missing in this import command. Yet this runs OK on my machine  (Ubuntu).

In my colleague's machine (Windows; I don't know if that makes a difference), Pycharm correctly generates  `from root.submodule.subsub import myfunction`, which runs OK on my machine too.

How do I get Pycharm  to generate the full path on my machine? How do I get Python and Pycharm to correctly tell me that the abbreviated path is an error?

Comment: Do you have several directories marked as `Sources Root`? (Folder icon being blue for these folders instead of grey)

Comment: *All* are gray. At the "Project Structure" settings, there is only one  Content Root, namely the parent directory of  `root`.

Comment: Right click on the Root folder you wish and click `Mark Directory as -> Sources Root`. Then see if the autogenerated import statements are different. In my experience, changing the directory marked as such, changes the behavior of these auto-generated statements.

Comment: OK, I did that, and it is blue. Let's see if that helps.

Comment: @Eskapp Would you like to add this as an answer so I can Accept?

Comment: I added an answer :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is due to the fact Pycharm does not detect the correct folder as the root of the project.

You can define any folder as the Root by right clicking on it going to `Mark Directory as -> Sources Root`. The folder color will change from grey to blue. Changing the Root directory changes the behavior of these auto-generated statements in my experience.